# Bitmap image choose from gallery not showing in imageview for android version 5.0.2

Tags: java, android

I found that my function of the app is not working for certain android phone.

I think maybe is the problem of android version? My app is working fine on an other Android phone, so how can I solve this issue?

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnupload,btnchoose;
    private ImageView imgprofile;

    Uri filepath;

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        btnchoose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_addphoto);
        btnupload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
        imgprofile = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        btnchoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                chooseimage();
            }
        });

        btnupload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void chooseimage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
    // Show only images, no videos or anything else
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            filepath = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),filepath);
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                    Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "YES!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, imgprofile.getWidth(),imgprofile.getHeight(),true);
                    imgprofile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "YES!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imgprofile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I run my app on the phone which is version 5.0.2 it does not show any response of toast.

Comment: You said that it does not show the toast. Does it displays the image?

Comment: no, nothing show at the imageview. but I put the code of chooseimage() inside btnchoose.setOnClickListener()... everything works fine. Thank you for your help =)

Answer (score 1):

This is the code works for me. I just change the position of the function, the code still the same.

```
package com.example.user8.letseat;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnupload,btnchoose;
private ImageView imgprofile;

Uri filepath;

private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
StorageReference storageReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();

    btnchoose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_addphoto);
    btnupload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
    imgprofile = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    btnchoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);
        }
    });

    btnupload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            uploadimage();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        filepath = data.getData();
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),filepath);
            imgprofile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void uploadimage() {
    if (filepath != null)
    {
        final ProgressDialog pg = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pg.setTitle("Uploading...");
        pg.show();
        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("image/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        ref.putFile(filepath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                pg.dismiss();
                DatabaseReference databaseReference ;
                databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Imageeee");
                String ImageUploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                String imageurl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                // Adding image upload id s child element into databaseReference.
                databaseReference.child(ImageUploadId).setValue(imageurl);
                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "FINISH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                pg.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "FAIL"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                pg.setMessage("Uploaded" + (int)progress+"%");
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**MyActivity.xml**

```
<ImageView

    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_x="13dp"
    android:layout_y="112dp" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivityextends Activity  {
    Button imageUpload;
    ImageView imageView;
    static final int PICTURE = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageUpload= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonImage);
        imageUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent,PICTURE);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==PICTURE && resultCode==RESULT_OK && null !=data)
        {

            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String[] prjection ={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri,prjection,null,null,null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(prjection[0]);
            String path=cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap selectFile = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);


            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(selectFile);
            imageView.setBackground(d);


           // imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));
        }
    }
}
```

Check Simple code of get image from gallery and display hopr this may help you.
[Example](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/20/select-an-image-from-gallery-in-android-and-show-it-in-an-imageview/)

Comment: @shinmin Thank you. if it is help to you then mark as a right and up vote this answer please :)